# If DateFormat is an abstract class how is it instantiated with getInstance() method

Tags: abstract-class

As per my understanding the interface and abstract class can not be instantiated. Then how could the DateFormat abstract class be instantiated with static factoy method getInstance() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the whole point of a factory method.

It returns an instance of DateFormat or of a subclass of DateFormat. You don't know which. You don't care which. You just care that all the methods of DateFormat are going to work.

Comment: I can understand that it can be an instance of Sub class of DateFormat but how could it be instance of DateFormat which is abstract class. When I try to return an instance of an abstract class compilelation error is thrown sating "Cannot instantiate type abstract". So it can not be object of DateFormat class but it can be explicitly casted to DateFormat. Am I right?